# Zend Framework Date Time Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, frameworks, zendx

I'm a real newbie in programming and finally got the ZendX Jquery to work. However, I would like to include a date time picker, and found an option at http://www.binpress.com/app/zfdatetimepicker/85 . However, the documentation is not complete and I would really want to set it up correctly. Can anyone help me with the steps required to do so? I tried setting it up and got the error " Object doesn't support property or method 'datetimepicker'". Thanks.

Comment: Nvm, I got it to work. My include path for the .js file was wrong.

Comment: how can you include your .js file please paste code

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to include the jquery UI script files. Looking at his [demo](http://www.binpress.com/app/demo/app/85), it is pulling in [jQuery UI 1.8.21](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js) from jquery's 'code' servers. I also know that without the UI component included, you will get the error message `Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'` when you do something like `$('#myDate').datepicker`. So I'm assuming you're just missing the correct script includes.

I've not used zend-framework at all, so I might be missing something on that side.